# Low bound exceeds high bound & Duplicate case label if you swap'em cntCaseTbl(Z : Int64): Int64; Error in Case Table

Tags: delphi, case

I'm getting this error on the code below:

> Low bound exceeds high bound

If you swap them, you get a different error:

> Duplicate case label

What can I do?

I've tried all of them without `Int64()` and with `Int64()`, but it didn't help.

Try for yourself, errors exist no matter if you type cast or not.

There's several ways to do this below, but I want to know why this code errors the way it does:

**Delphi can not use below because it can not achieve 64-bit processing on case statements.**

```
function cntCaseTbl(Z: Int64): Int64;
  begin
    case Abs(Z) of
      0..9: Exit(1);
      10..99: Exit(2);
      100..999: Exit(3);
      1000..9999: Exit(4);
      10000..99999: Exit(5);
      100000..999999: Exit(6);
      1000000..9999999: Exit(7);
      10000000..99999999: Exit(8);
      100000000..999999999: Exit(9);
      1000000000..9999999999: Exit(10);
      10000000000..99999999999: Exit(11);
      100000000000..999999999999: Exit(12);
      1000000000000..9999999999999: Exit(13);
      10000000000000..99999999999999: Exit(14);
      100000000000000..999999999999999: Exit(15);
      1000000000000000..9999999999999999: Exit(16);
      10000000000000000..99999999999999999: Exit(17);
      100000000000000000..999999999999999999: Exit(18);
      1000000000000000000..9223372036854775807: Exit(19);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Alright... removed the picture and put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 131, `10000000000` and `99999999999` are `Integer`s that are being type-casted to `Int64`, and they are both outside of the range of `Integer`, so they are overflowing before being casted, thus causing the 1st value to be less than the 2nd value, hence the error.

Same with the other lines, too.

This is described in Delphi's documentation:

[Case Statements](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Case_Statements)

> The case statement may provide a readable alternative to deeply nested if conditionals. A case statement has the form:
>
> ```
> case selectorExpression of
>   caseList1: statement1;
>    ...
>   caseListn: statementn;
> end
> ```
>
> where *selectorExpression* is any expression of an ordinal type **smaller than 32 bits** (string types and ordinals **larger than 32 bits** are invalid) ...

I would suggest getting rid of the `case` altogether and just use a loop instead, eg:

```
function cntCaseTbl(Z: Int64): Int64;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Z := Abs(Z);
  while Z > 0 do begin
    Inc(Result);
    Z := Z div 10;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As I stated above: "I've tried all of them without int64() and with int64() ... it didn't help."   The case Table proved to be faster on ticks vs all other methods other than assembly.

Comment: "*As I stated above*" - you added that after I had posted my answer.

Comment: I should have explained earlier that I was not seeking a alternative method, sorry.

Comment: So, I re-read the documents on the docwiki for embarcadero's website and I better understand your answer. "(string types and ordinals larger than 32 bits are invalid)"   So, Delphi is limited to 32 bits for case statements :(

Comment: The documentation is wrong: "an ordinal type smaller than 32 bits" should be "an ordinal type no larger than 32 bits".

Comment: Do you know if there's a way that I can create my own reserved word "case64"?

Comment: @GregT you can't create your own reserved keywords. They are intrinsic to the compiler.